# R grouped time series correlations with tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse

I want time series correlations in a grouped data frame. Here's a sample dataset:

```
x <- cbind(expand.grid(type = letters[1:4], time = seq(1:4), kind = letters[5:8]), value = rnorm(64)) %>% arrange(type, time, kind)
```

which produces 64 rows of the variables `type`, `time`, `kind` and `value`.

I want a time series correlation of the values for each `kind` grouped by `type`. Think of each `type` and `time` combination as an ordered vector of 4 values. I group by `type` and `time`, then arrange by `kind`, then remove `kind`.

```
y <- x %>% group_by(type) %>% arrange(type, time, kind) %>% select(-kind)
```

I can then group `y` by type and time and nest such that all the values are together in the data variable, regroup by `type` only and create a new variable which is the lead `data`.

```
z <- y %>% group_by(type, time) %>% nest(value) %>% group_by(type) %>% mutate(ahead = lead(data))
```

Now I want to run `mutate(R = cor(data, ahead))`, but I can't seem get the syntax correct.

I've also tried `mutate(R = cor(data$value, ahead$value))` and `mutate(R = cor(data[1]$value, ahead[1]$value))`, to no avail.

The error I get from `cor` is: `supply both 'x' and 'y' or a matrix-like 'x'`.

How do I reference the data and ahead variables as vectors to run with `cor`?

Ultimately, I'm looking for a 16 row data frame with columns `type`, `time`, and `R` where R is a single correlation value.

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `map2_dbl` from `purrr` to pass `data` and `ahead` at the same time to `cor` function.

```
library(dplyr)

z %>%
  mutate(R = purrr::map2_dbl(data, ahead, cor)) %>%
  select(-data, -ahead)

#  type   time     R
#  <fct> <int>   <dbl>
# 1 a         1  0.358 
# 2 a         2 -0.0498
# 3 a         3 -0.654 
# 4 a         4  1     
# 5 b         1 -0.730 
# 6 b         2  0.200 
# 7 b         3 -0.928 
# 8 b         4  1     
# 9 c         1  0.358 
#10 c         2  0.485 
#11 c         3 -0.417 
#12 c         4  1     
#13 d         1  0.140 
#14 d         2 -0.448 
#15 d         3 -0.511 
#16 d         4  1
```

In base R, we can use `mapply`

```
z$R <- mapply(cor, z$data, z$ahead)
```